# Break point not calling in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitter, breakpoints

I am trying to debug my code using a break point, but the break point does not get called. The issues happens when i use `Build and debug`.

> warning: Could not open fork matching current architecture for OSO archive "/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a"
>
> warning: Could not open OSO file /Users/xxx/Desktop/POCNew/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a(config.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/sribharanidharans/Desktop/xxx/build/Debug-iphoneos/yyy.app/yyy
>
> warning: Could not open fork matching current architecture for OSO archive "/Users/xxx/Desktop/yyy/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a"
>   .....
>
> warning: Could not open fork matching current architecture for OSO archive "/Users/xxx/Desktop/POCNew/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine/libOAuth.a"
>
> warning: Could not open OSO file /Users/xxx/Desktop/yyy/Twitter+OAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine/libOAuth.a(hmac.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/xxx/Desktop/yyy/build/Debug-iphoneos/yyy.app/yyy
>   .....

Comment: give proper path in (header search path) in target

Comment: are you adding breakpoints in libararies?

Comment: @Ravin adding breakpoints in libraries means? i'm using break point in normal line

Comment: As in warning log we can see that there are few external libaries are used. So I am asking exactly where break-point are in your code. Are they in library related files? Is debugger is able to resolve breakpoints.

Comment: @Ravin I'm not using any break points in library files and one more thing is debugger not able to stop in break points.

Answer (score 0):

Once keep break point either in `viewDidLoad/init` and check whether it is getting called or not. According to my understanding the app is getting crashed before it hits the breakpoint & if you can a attach screenshot it will be easy for us to help you.